# Trying to run a ternary condition which sets an image(if undefined) to an image in my src folder. But throws an error saying it's undefined

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm trying to run a ternary conditional which, if the object is undefined, will replace it with an image I have in my src folder. And if the object is defined, then the image is the one from the API I'm trying to load it. But it keeps throwing an erorr that the object is undefined, even though I'm resetting it to something which for sure is defined.

```
> render() {
>        const dogList = this.state.Dogs.map( Dog  =>{
>           const dogPic = (Dog.media.photos.photo[2].$t !== undefined ? Dog.media.photos.photo[0].$t : noPic)
>            return(
>                <div className="box1" key={Dog.id.$t}><div className='text1'>{Dog.name.$t} | {Dog.age.$t}<Link
> to={`/Dogs/${Dog.id.$t}`}><img className="dog1" src={noPic}/></Link>
>                </div></div>
>            )
>        })
```

Comment: I think you better show your error line number. In your case, `Dog` can be undefined. `photos` can be undefined. So many things can be undefined in short

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'photo' of undefined
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/Asimov-ReBorn/Desktop/Web Development/workingreact/src/Dogs.js:24
  21 | }
  22 | render() {
  23 |     const dogList = this.state.Dogs.map( Dog  =>{
> 24 |        const dogPic = (Dog.media.photos.photo[2].$t !== undefined ? Dog.media.photos.photo[2].$t : noPic)
  25 |         return(
  26 |             <div className="box1" key={Dog.id.$t}><div className='text1'>{Dog.name.$t} | {Dog.age.$t}<Link to={`/Dogs/${Dog.id.$t}`}><img className="dog1" src={noPic}/></Link>
  27 |             </div></div>

Comment: please check if your Dog.media.photos has any values

Comment: so dog.media.photos returns with different information if it doesn't have a photo in it. but if it does it returns with dog.media.photos.photo[photo number goes here].$t<- the actual photo value.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you want it. you need to check `Dog.media.photos.photo[2]` exists first.

```
render() {
        const dogList = this.state.Dogs.map(Dog => {
            const dogPic =
                (!!Dog.media.photos.photo[2] && Dog.media.photos.photo[2].$t !== undefined)
                    ? Dog.media.photos.photo[0].$t
                    : noPic;
            return (
                <div className="box1" key={Dog.id.$t}>
                    <div className="text1">
                        {Dog.name.$t} | {Dog.age.$t}
                        <Link to={`/Dogs/${Dog.id.$t}`}>
                            <img className="dog1" src={noPic} />
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        });
    }
```